# Counting number of items in a single-row CSV file?

Tags: scripting, unix-shell, csv

I have a file containing a long comma-delimited list of numbers, like this:

```
2,8,42,75,101
```

What's the simplest command (from a Unix shell) to get the count of numbers in this file? In the example above, that would be `5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest is probably to just count the commas:

```
sed 's/[^,]//g' yourfile.csv | wc -c
```

Normally you'd add one to get the number of elements, but if there's a newline there it's counted too.  Convenient in this case, I guess.

Also with awk:

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' yourfile.csv
```

Comment: Going with this approach, with a small twist - sedding the commas to spaces then using wc -w to get the word count.

Answer (score 1):

as per here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/finding-bash-shell-array-length-elements/

this isnt too difficult

if you can define your list of elements in an array like so:

```
ArrayName=("element 1" "element 2" "element 3")
```

then its as simple as:

```
echo ${#ArrayName[@]}
```

however you have a csv so this may be better: http://www.thelinuxblog.com/working-with-csv-files-in-bash/

```
echo $(cat file.csv | sed ‘s/, /_ /g’ | tr ‘,’ ‘\n’ | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution:

```
cat file.csv | sed 's/,/ /g' | wc -w
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use python you could do:

```
str = given_csv_line_as_string
if str[-1] == ',': str = str[:-1]
print len(given_csv_line_as_string.split(','))
```

Note that this will return the correct length regardless if there is a hanging comma.

I'm sure there is something similar and more sysadmin-y in perl but I don't use perl.

Answer (score 0):

Or use grep

```
grep -o "," | wc -l
```

Actually to get this correct you would need to add one to the result